# cron.php does not work

Tags: cron, ce-1.9.2.0

I am trying to start the cronjob via shell, as it does not execute via crontab.

When I type `php5 cron.php`
The output is only

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.26
Content-type: text/html
```

And no jobs are beeing executed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the CLI version of PHP. Ask your hoster which command to use or if you want to try finding it yourself, type:

```
ls -l `which php5`
```

which shows you where `php5` is located and if it is a symlink. then look in the directory (or the directory of the symlink) if you can find something like `php5-cli`

Also, you should specify the mode like this:

```
php cron.php -mdefault
php cron.php -malways
```

Otherwise, cron.php starts cron.sh which then spawns cron.php again with both variations. Also it redirects all output to `/dev/null`.

I strongly recommend using the alternative cron runner from [Aoe_Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) which gives you much more control and information. Also it explains you exactly how to set up the system cronjob.

Comment: I tried `/usr/local/.../bin/php-cli cron.php -mdefault` and I get back: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /home/.../cron.php on line 43`which is `Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
` The funny thing is, that everything worked well before the 1.9.2 update.

Comment: I resolved it now by adding `-mdefault` to the php5-5.5 command.